# Calling custom R functions from Java

Tags: java, r, function-calls

I have look into rJava and checked out a video on RCaller, but in all examples I saw people are only calling native R functions. I have found no way of loading a *.r file and using its content.

The main question is: How to integrate a custom Rscript in Java, so that I can call my custom-made R functions through java?

The thing that I want to do is to create a simple GUI with images loaded from folders, buttons and be able to call my custom R functions on click and dynamically swapping images depending on outcomes(the logic would be in R).

Comment: If a direct Java -> R is not possible then you could always adopt Java -> (JNI) -> C / C++ -> R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practice would be to hide the R code behind an abstraction, i.e., an interface. Once the interface has been defined, call `rJavax::setJavaImplementation()` to define an R reference class that implements the interface.

An alternative solution (but not a direct answer to your question) would be to use e.g. the gWidgets package to create your GUI in R. That should be much easier than attempting the same with Java/Swing.

Answer (score 0):

you can still stay with RCaller using R's source() function to open and read an external R script and call its content using RCaller.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old post. However one solution would be to use `source('path of R script')` R command in your Java code to import the functionality written in external R script.

There is also a blog on integration of R with Java [http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rserve/][1]
which describes the process under heading '**Calling User-defined R functions in Java**'